# Custom Admin grid TimeZOne - Date issue in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, timezone

I have set default time zone pacific standard time(america/los_angeles)

In admin gridwhen i inline edit date

i take 31 aug 2018 but once it save it display 30 aug 2018.

see in images:

[image]

[image]

Have anyone face this issue or have any solution for it?

Comment: this because of timezone you have selected. Change the time zone and check.

Comment: India is 12 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Los Angeles

Comment: India is 12 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Los Angeles- * so how can i achieve that with  Los Angeles timezone? @MandarParbate

Comment: You need not to do anything, this is not an issue. @Rutvee Sojitra

Comment: Ofcourse it's issue  if currently i am  saving current date 22nd aug 2018 it should be 22nd instead of i am getting 21st aug 2018
India is 12 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Los Angeles- Still both country has same date

Comment: You can change the time zone from backend to indian timezone and check

Comment: It depends on the time you are selecting the dates

Comment: i am selecting current date and time what will be my output?
is shouldn't 22nd aug?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82056/discussion-between-mandar-parbate-and-rutvee-sojitra).